# MySQL Cluster SQL Node not synchronizing

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL Cluster and am trying to setup a new cluster for our new application.  Here is what I have set up on 5 CentOS 64 bit VM and got the cluster  to work using MySQL Cluster 7.2.  I am trying to test it and have some issues.

“I have successfully installed the Cluster with 5 nodes (2 Data, 1 Mgmt and 2 SQL Nodes). While testing the cluster I have hit on one scenario where I am stuck and cannot make it to work. Here is the screen shot of the Management Node displaying all cluster nodes:

```
ndb_mgm> show
Cluster Configuration
---------------------
[ndbd(NDB)]     2 node(s)
id=2  @10.0.3.138  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12, Nodegroup: 0)
id=3  @10.0.3.83  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12, Nodegroup: 0, Master)

[ndb_mgmd(MGM)] 1 node(s)
id=1  @10.0.3.135  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12)

[mysqld(API)]   2 node(s)
id=4  @10.0.3.87  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12)
id=5  @10.0.3.22  (mysql-5.5.30 ndb-7.2.12)

ndb_mgm>
```

Here is the scenario:

While all nodes in the cluster are working as a part of my test I shut down one of the SQL Node 4 and while this node is offline, I drop a database which is part of the cluster databases on SQL Node 5. When I bring up the offline SQL Node 4 and rejoin to the cluster the dropped database still shows up. It should sync with the old cluster databases meaning the dropped database when the SQL Node 4 was offline should be removed from the cluster and should not show up on SQL Node 4. This is a real scenario that can happen.

Also, I am searching for MySQL Cluster Test document which describes these scenarios and cannot seem to find it. “

Any Help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There can be issues regarding the syncing of the FRMs stored centrally in the data nodes and the local copies on each MySQL Server. The workaround is to stop the mysqld; delete the FRM files for Cluster tables (and DB in this case) from the mysqld's datadir; start mysqld and then run SHOW TABLES.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  What if there are no errors will the schema and data be synchronized when SQL Node rejoins the cluster in normal circumstance.